# How to set to object parallel in Html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making two sign-up forms using html and CSS Bootstrap. I want the two forms to be in parallel and for the second i am using the  `position` tag of html but without success because even if i the forms are parallel there seems to be created not needed space.
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83wqt.jpg)
Is there a way to prevent that space which i circled not to be created?

```
          <main class="my-form">
                   <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-flex-start">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Apliko</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form name="my-form" onsubmit="return validform()" action="success.php" method="">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="full_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Emri juaj:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="emri" class="form-control" name="emri">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email_address" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Adresa Email:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email-address">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="user_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Subjekti:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="subjekti" class="form-control" name="subjekti">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Mesazhi:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="mesazhi" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">CV-ja juaj:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="file">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunction(), location.href = 'index.html'">
                                    Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This was the first form. I started the second one like this.

```
     <main  style="position:sticky; left:680px; top:2px; width:900px; ">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-flex-end">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Rregjistrohu si 
          perdorues</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form name="my-form" onsubmit="return validform()" action="success.php" method="">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="full_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Emer Mbiemer:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="full_name" class="form-control" name="full-name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: There's something else going on with your CSS. Try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (this helps you figure out what's actually wrong, instead of just getting an answer for this situation).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use CSS boostrap, you can use Flex properties to set two containers in parallel

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div>YOUR FIRST FORM HERE</div>
    <div>YOUR SECOND FORM HERE</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;   
}

.flexContainer div{
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Your code will be shorter

Comment: You can't next CSS rules like that `div` you have in there (you can in SCSS, though).

Comment: Sorry, I am used to SCSS

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be manual width issue.
Horizontal scroll is due to excess manual width.
As you are using Bootstrap framework, it already gives you flexibility, So try to avoid defining manual width.
I have simplified the code structure.

[Simplified Form Structure - Snippet](https://codepen.io/Akshay25/pen/ZNqaqz)

Hope so this will resolve your issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<main>
        <div class="bg-light py-3 mb-4">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla qui quisquam sit harum labore iusto cum, temporibus est soluta voluptatibus! Fugiat doloremque facere suscipit porro dolore odio harum vero at!</p>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Profile</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="full_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="emri" class="form-control" name="emri">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="email_address" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Email ID:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email-address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="user_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Subject:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="subjekti" class="form-control" name="subjekti">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Address:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="mesazhi" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Updated CV:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="file">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunction(), location.href = 'index.html'">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Profile</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="full_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="emri" class="form-control" name="emri">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="email_address" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Email ID:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email-address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="user_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Subject:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="subjekti" class="form-control" name="subjekti">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Address:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="mesazhi" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">New Field-1:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="mesazhi" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">New Field-2:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="mesazhi" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone_number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Updated CV:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="file">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunction(), location.href = 'index.html'">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- col-md-6 -->
            </div>
            <!-- row -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it quickly maybe with:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it cant overflow the screen on the sides then. Maximum is the width of your screen, 100 viewport width. Rest is hidden. In your CSS